# How to remove the embed_footer?

Tags: functions, embed, oembed

I'm trying to remove the entire [embed_footer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_footer/) from WordPress embedded posts.

By adding the following code in the `functions.php`, I was able to remove the site title and comments icon. But still, the share icon is there.

```
add_filter('embed_site_title_html','__return_false');
remove_action( 'embed_content_meta', 'print_embed_comments_button' );
```

Is there a way to remove the entire `embed_footer`? Or can I remove the share button also like the above code?

Comment: If the action was created using a specific priority value I think you'll need to pass the same value when removing it for it to work.

Comment: It's loaded inside wordpress core files.: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_footer/

Answer (score 0):

The comments button and the share button are generated in two separate default actions, so you have to remove them both:

```
remove_action( 'embed_content_meta', 'print_embed_comments_button' );
remove_action( 'embed_content_meta', 'print_embed_sharing_button' );
```

Answer (score -1):

All the javascript files are embedded in the footer if you remove the footer maybe your site goes down. There are two ways:

1. Create a child theme and create footer.php and call `wp_footer();` hook there.
2. Or If you just want to remove the footer text you can do this in CSS just find the class or id and make it `display: none;`

Comment: I'm asking about https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_footer/. You misunderstood the question.